# Custom animation for collapsible set not working in jQuerymobile 1.4.0

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have the following collapsible set in my jQuery mobile 1.4.0  App, I  need to add an animation to this collapsible set when its expanded and closed , I have tried this code and its working ok  in jsfiddle ,this is  my  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HZZd/1/) ,but The problem is that the animation didn't work on my app with  jquery mobile 1.4.0 . How can i make this animation works on jQuery mobile 1.4.0? please help me ..

the javascript code for animation

```
<script>
$('document').on('pageinit',function(){    

      animateCollapsibleSet($("[data-role='collapsible-set'] > [data-role='collapsible']"));

 });

 // animation speed;
 var animationSpeed = 200;

 function animateCollapsibleSet(elm) 
 {

      // can attach events only one time, otherwise we create infinity loop;
         elm.one("expand", function() {

     // hide the other collapsibles first;
         $(this).parent().find(".ui-collapsible-content").not(".ui-collapsible-content- collapsed").trigger("collapse");

    // animate show on collapsible;
         $(this).find(".ui-collapsible-content").slideDown(animationSpeed, function() {

    // trigger original event and attach the animation again;
        animateCollapsibleSet($(this).parent().trigger("expand"));
   });

 // we do our own call to the original event;
   return false;
   }).one("collapse", function() 
    {

        // animate hide on collapsible;
        $(this).find(".ui-collapsible-content").slideUp(animationSpeed, function() {

            // trigger original event;
            $(this).parent().trigger("collapse");
        });

        // we do our own call to the original event;
        return false;
    });
   }



</script>
```

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3LvQh/

Comment: @OmarThanks it worked but there is 2 problems: the first one if i expand Governorate1 then expand Governorate2 the Governorate1 didn't closed automatically and i need to click on it 2 times in order to close it How can we  update this code  to be as the previous one when we click fore example Governorate2 if Governorate1 is expanded it will close automatically.

Comment: Small update to Omar's code to close other open collapsibles: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3LvQh/3/

Comment: @ezankerThanks a lot the problem solved , but there is another issue which is i have  more than one Country collapsible in my page and when i expand the second Country collapsible all its   Governorates are  Expanded then they all closed , How can i fix this line  $(".ui-collapsible:not(:eq(0)).. To solve this problem can you help me more please ?

Comment: remove `:not(:eq(0))`. btw, `collapse` and `expand` events are now `collapsiblecollapse` and `collapsibleexpand`. so maybe replacing old events with new ones might solve your problem too, including `.trigger("event")`.

Comment: @OmarI removed :not(:eq(0)) ,but the issue still check this  http://jsfiddle.net/3LvQh/4/

Comment: I assume the countries are in a collapsible set too? If so try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3LvQh/5/

Comment: @ezankerThis is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/3LvQh/6/ I was  updated this to show you what i have but sorry a bout my late , you are faster than me and i see that you worked for another way

Comment: @ezankerI am sorry , I make you work a lot, but i have tried to solve this issue http://jsfiddle.net/3LvQh/6/  but it didn't work for me how can we fix that all collapsible are expanded together then they closed?

Comment: Here is your updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3LvQh/7/

Comment: @OmarThanks also for your help ..

Comment: You're welcome :) @ezanker add an answer, get some rep.

Comment: @Omar thanks, I have added it as an answer. Your initial fiddle definitely made my work easier ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given multiple countries as collapsibles (not in a set) and each country contains a collapsible set with several collapsibles. The markup looks like this:

```
<div data-role="content">
     <div data-role="collapsible"  data-iconpos="left"  data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" class="col" >
    <h3 ><div>Country 1</div></h3>

    <div data-role="collapsible-set"  data-iconpos="left"   data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" class="governorates"> 
        <div data-role="collapsible"  >
                <h3 class="Mycollapsible"><div style="color:white;font-weight:normal;">Governorate1</div></h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle">Village1</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village2</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village3</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village4</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village5</font></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3 class="Mycollapsible"><div style="color:white;font-weight:normal;" >Governorate2</div></h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle">Village1</font> </li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village2</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village3</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village4</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village5</font></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible"  data-iconpos="left"  data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" class="col" >
        <h3 ><div>Country 2</div></h3>
        <div data-role="collapsible-set"  data-iconpos="left"   data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" class="governorates"> 
            <div data-role="collapsible"  >
                <h3 class="Mycollapsible"><div style="color:white;font-weight:normal;">Governorate1</div></h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle">Village1</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village2</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village3</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village4</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village5</font></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3 class="Mycollapsible"><div style="color:white;font-weight:normal;" >Governorate2</div></h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle">Village1</font> </li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village2</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village3</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village4</font></li>
                    <li data-icon='false'>  <font class="NameStyle"> Village5</font></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In javascript, I handle the country expand/collapse separately from the second level collapsible sets by adding a class `.governorates` to the collapsible sets

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', function () {
    $(".governorates .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").on("click", function (e) {        
        var current = $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible");
        if (current.hasClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")) {
            $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).slideDown("fast", function () {
                current.trigger("collapsibleexpand");  
                //hide previously expanded
                $(".governorates  .ui-collapsible-content-collapsed").slideUp('fast');                    
            });
        } else {
            $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).slideUp("fast", function () {
                current.trigger("collapsiblecollapse");
            });
        }
    });

    $(".col .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").not(".governorates .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").on("click", function (e) {        
        var current = $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible");             
        if (current.hasClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")) {
            $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).not(".governorates .ui-collapsible-content").slideDown("fast", function () {
                current.trigger("collapsibleexpand");  
            });
        } else {
            $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).not(".governorates .ui-collapsible-content").slideUp("fast", function () {
                current.trigger("collapsiblecollapse");
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3LvQh/7/)** (Based on Omar's initial work in the OP comment thread).

Comment: Two remarks for the posterity: 1) i believe triggering `expand`and `collapse` events in code is a doublette. 2) jQuery's  `slide` functions are adding the style directly to the element, so subsequent invocations of `collapsible("collapse")` aren't working properly anymore - must use `removeAttr("style")`or always doing another `slideUp` / `slideDown` before invoking respectively `collapse` or `expand`.

Answer (score 0):

I know an answer has already been selected, but, here I've forked ezanker's fiddle, doing the same thing, but with less code.

http://jsfiddle.net/fussycashew/EZ2Kx/

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    $("[data-role='collapsible']").collapsible({

        collapse: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).children().next().slideUp(150);
        },
        expand: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).children().next().hide();
            $(this).children().next().slideDown(150);
        }

    });
});
```