# JQuery Mobile Collapsable Slide Transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, animation, jquery-mobile-collapsible

Has anyone been able to add a slide transition to the JQuery Collapsible property?

I am trying to make a list that is collapsable with *data-inset="false"*, and when the user taps the menu item, the collapsed section slides out.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do (but with JQuery Mobile instead), however, in this example, the transition is not as smooth as I would like it: http://www.designgala.com/demos/collapse-expand-jquery.html

Ideas?

Note: I have seen other posts with a similar objective, however, none of the posts used the transition I described, they used a fade.

Comment: do you have any example code that we could help fix up?  I would suggest placing your data inside of a div that has `overflow:hidden` then animating the container div open while the div inside of it stretches to the right height

Comment: I was actually wondering if someone could provide some example code, as I am not sure where to start with the transitions.

Comment: take a look at jQuery `.slideUp` and `.slideDown` https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/.  These both work with mobile and are pretty smooth if you do them correctly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom animation for collapsible set not working in jQuerymobile 1.4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417176/custom-animation-for-collapsible-set-not-working-in-jquerymobile-1-4-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple and concise bit of JS that I use to animate my collapsible sets.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    $("[data-role='collapsible']").collapsible({

        collapse: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).children().next().slideUp(150);
        },
        expand: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).children().next().hide();
            $(this).children().next().slideDown(150);
        }

    });
});
```

Here's a [demo in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fussycashew/EZ2Kx/).

Comment: Hmm, this did not work for me without giving pageinit a page argument.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that I'm trying to get this to work on collapsibles that are injected to dom via ajax after pageinit event, I think.