# How do I insert global code to create animation for all collapsibles?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using JQM 1.4.5.

I am trying to animate all collapsible content so they slide open and close when the header. I almost have it working with this:

```
$(document).on('collapsibleexpand', '.animateMe', function() {
    $("[data-role='collapsible']").collapsible({

        collapse: function( event, ui ) { 
            $(this).children().next().slideUp(150);
        },  
        expand: function( event, ui ) { 
            $(this).children().next().hide();
            $(this).children().next().slideDown(150);
        }   
    }); 
});
```

The problem with this code is that I have to click at least one collapsible before the animation code kicks in.

I could do something like this:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#pageA", function(){
   /* ABOVE CODE GOES HERE */
});
```

The problem with this solution is I have to write this code for each one of my pages. I tried the solution at [JQuery Mobile Collapsable Slide Transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543372/jquery-mobile-collapsable-slide-transition) which my code is based on but the "pageinit" doesn't seem to work at all without giving it a page argument.

So how do I put this animation code into my js file so that it gets triggered for all collapsibles across all pages?

Comment: I've tried changing `pageinit` to `mobileinit` but that is not working either.

Comment: OK, I see part of the problem. The code actually works with mobileinit but not on elements that are getting pulled in via ajax after mobileinit. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the create event of the collapsible widget and event delegation to make sure it runs on dynamically added collapsibles:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-create

```
$(document).on("collapsiblecreate","[data-role='collapsible']",  function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).collapsible({   
        collapse: function( event, ui ) { 
            $(this).children().next().slideUp(450);
        },  
        expand: function( event, ui ) { 
            $(this).children().next().hide();
            $(this).children().next().slideDown(450);
        }   
    }); 
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xv64y7jo/)**

In my demo, I am attaching the event in the pagebeforeevent of the first page.  You might be able to use mobileinit or another event as long as it runs before any non-dynamic collapsibles are initialized.

Comment: Bingo. You've just ended hours of frustration.

Comment: I had considered the idea of binding the expand/collapses event to the ajax's calls returned html but had no idea how to do that until you told me about the create method. I was trying all kinds of crazy stuff to get this working properly. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something similar now with a button. This works but doesn't feel right:

    `$(document).on("buttoncreate", function( e, ui ) { 
       $('.map_link').on('click', function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();              
     }); 
   });`

I'm basically adding the same bit of code to a single class over and over. What's the proper wa to pull this off?

Comment: I have a button in a collapsible header. When I tap the button, I don't want the collapsible to expand/contract so I have the `e.stopPropagation()` bits in there. The code I have there in my last cmment works. But I'm adding the code to the class `.map_link` which seems sloppy to me.